# How can I access a test class from Maven's main folder?

Tags: maven, testing

I created a Maven project with the standard folder strucure - i.e. src/main/java, src/test/java, etc.

I wrote a class ClassA and a test class TestA.

From the main program of ClassA, I refer to a static member of TestA.

The code compiles, but when I run it, I get: NoClassDefFoundError: TestA.

How can I access TestA from within ClassA?

Comment: This looks like a questionable design decision to me. Why would your main application depend on a test class?

Comment: Btw. the issue you are experiencing is intentional - thus maven separates the tests from the aplication.

Comment: I access TestA from ClassA.main. This is a convenience - while I develop ClassA, it allows me to run some tests easily bu running ClassA.main.

Comment: The code under *src/main/* is intended to be productive code which will be shipped in any kind of meaning. On the other hand the code under */src/test/* is intended for unit testing only which is not productive code. So the only way can be having a dependency from your test code to your productive *but never* the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of solving your issue directly, I would advise to rethink your test design. Maven is perfectly capable of running tests on its own, just enter

`mvn test`

on the command line. If you want to run a single test class, enter

`mvn test -Dtest=MyTest`

for a single test method, use

`mvn test -Dtest=MyTest#shouldRunPerfectly`

It also supports wildcards, so to run some common tests, you could type

`mvn test -Dtest=Integration*#shouldBeFaster*`.

Most IDEs allow to run tests directly by a shortcut. If I recall correctly, It's **<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>** then **<kbd>T</kbd>** for Eclipse and **<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>** for IntelliJ. IntelliJ also uses the **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>** shortcut to navigate to the test of the class you are working with.

Maven directory structure emphasizes the separation of the tests from the application and makes it much harder to do what you are planning to.

tl;dr - do it the maven way