# maven: how import from test classes in class from main

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to compile maven project. I have main and test folders and pom.xml. In Util.java class of main folderI use variabe of class BaseTest.java, which belongs to folder test. I have equal packages in main and test folder: com.tests. In Util.java class I imported BaseTest.java, like:

```
import com.tests.TestBase;
```

I got error:

```
[ERROR] E:\test\src\main\java\com\tests.Util.java:[18,24] error: package BaseTest does not exist
```

Then I try set `import test.java.com.tests.TestBase;` I got error also. So how can I import from test folder?

Comment: The purpose of the separation of main and test code is to prevent test and product code from getting intermixed.  You can by pass this with Maven, but you should think twice about your code structure first.

Comment: Can you show your project structure? The error states that the `package` doesn't exists so some where of your application you should have a structure like src\BaseTest\Util.java

Comment: image of the project explorer may be more helpful for finding the solution

Comment: @Chris K: I see, so I think about project structure, I need both - main and test. But I have managed my problem: I reach needed variables via additional metod parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't do it. Maybe you can run the test directly: `mvn test -Dtest=TestBase`. Check this thread: [How can I access a test class from Maven's main folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873285/how-can-i-access-a-test-class-from-mavens-main-folder)